# He is better than his brother. Positive degree

Tags: sentence-meaning, adjectives

How can we change this sentence into positive degree without changing its meaning?

Comment: Can you give us some of your thoughts on how to change it? Technically, I'm not sure you can, as the statement is inherently comparative. If the statement was : "*He is better at math[s] than his brother.*" the change is simple: "*He is good at math.*" But you're not explaining **what** he's better at, just that he's generally "better". I suppose you could just turn the sentence into "*He is good.*"... but that requires knowing what he's good at.

Comment: I mean to say,  how can we change the form of sentence into positive degree?

Comment: I understand that... I'm asking for more information.

Comment: Sorry,  I can't add more information. Because I am not sure myself.

Comment: Do you know what "positive degree" is?

Comment: Yeah,  I know about positive degree.

Comment: John is a tall boy. 
John is taller than Ancy. 
John is tallest of them all. 
In the first sentence it explains only that, John is a tall boy. Here John is not compared with any others. In such cases, when adjective is used with out any comparison to other nouns we call it as POSITIVE DEGREE. 

In the second sentence the adjective is used for comparison between two people, such cases when adjective is used for comaprison of two person,thing we call it as COMPARATIVE DEGREE . In Comparative Degree use 'than' after the adjectives. 
taller than 
greater than 
In third sentence the comparison is b

Comment: I added all the degrees. So that you may catch me easily.

Comment: Add the information to your question, not as a comment. If you understand what the degrees are, what trouble are you having with this question?

Comment: My sentence is given in comparative degree.  I want to change this into positive degree without changing its meaning?

Comment: That is impossible. If you make it into positive degree, you must remove the comparison to his brother, which requires making the sentence simply "He is good".

Comment: You could go with "he and his brother are both good", but then you lose meaning regarding the comparison. Like @Catija has said, that sentence contains a comparison. If you drop the comparison, it doesn't have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Changing something from comparative degree (or superlative degree) into the positive involves removing the comparison to other things or people and changing the form of the adjective/adverb.

"Better" is an irregular adjective. The three degrees are "good", "better", and "best". So, if you want to make something into the positive degree, you use the word "good".

> *He is good.*

This can sound a bit odd because "[good](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/good_1)" (when used alone) has the added meaning of "behaving in a moral fashion".

> 14. *behaving correctly or being right according to accepted moral standards*

It is similar to "he is a good person".

To avoid this "better" is usually defined more specifically by saying **what** someone is better at or **how** something is better:

> This cake *tastes* better than that one.
>   I'm better at math than at writing.

The positive forms of these statements are, respectively:

> This cakes tastes good.
>   I'm good at math.

So, perhaps a slight change to your sentence is in order.

Comment: Sir , What about this sentence? He is as good as his brother.

Comment: I'm not a sir. You're certainly using the positive *form* of the degree but you've completely changed the meaning of the sentence... the original sentence says that he is *better* and this version is saying they are **the same**.

Comment: How would you like to change this sentence into positive degree without changing its meaning?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not going to keep answering the question over and over. I've already explained that it's, essentially, impossible. **Why** do you need to do this?

Comment: Okay,  no worries .Thanks for your kind information.